# Is it possible to rename the master branch on Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

I no longer use `master` as the default git remote branch and now use `main`.  I have configured [GitHub](https://www.github.com) so it is now the default remote for merging pull requests.  I deploy to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com), is there a way to change the default branch on Heroku to be `main` instead of `master`.  I would like to call

```
git push heroku main
```

Instead of

```
git push heroku main:master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku already uses both branches `main` and `master` to deploy:

Just do this in your existing app:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b main    
git push heroku main
```

**Source:** [Branches](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-branches)

Comment: It would help to include the first part of that article in your answer: "Heroku deploys from the main and master branches. When you push either of those branches to the heroku remote, Heroku builds and runs the pushed code as the latest version of your app. Note that pushing code to any other branch has no effect." Historically, Heroku has only built from `master`, and a push to `main` wouldn't have done anything useful. You should also quote sections you quote from official documentation by prefixing with `>` or selecting the quoted text and clicking the `”` button.